# How do I get 100% code coverage for "catch with rethrow" block in VB.NET in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage, mstest

I am unable to achieve 100% code coverage for a "catch with rethrow" block in my VB.NET source code.  My workplace IDE is Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Below example represents a simplified version of my actual problem.

**Source in C#: (light-blue background indicates full code coverage)**

[image: Source in C#]

**Equivalent source in VB.NET: (yellow background indicates partial code coverage)**

[image: Source in VB.NET]

**MSTests for both C# and VB.NET source (intended to achieve 100% code coverage)**

[image: MSTests]

**Code Coverage Report**

[image: Code Coverage Report]

The code coverage report shows 100% for C#, but only 91.67% for VB.NET. It also shows 1 block of code with 0 lines being uncovered in VB.NET.

Is this an issue with the tool? Or am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT #1:** Sharing source code as requested by @Raptor

**Source code in C#**

```
public class CodeCoverage
{
   public void DoWork(bool flag = false)
   {
      try
      {
         Thread.Sleep(1);

        if (flag)
            {
               throw new Exception("test");
            }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         throw new Exception(string.Format("something happened: {0}", ex.Message));
      }
   }
}
```

**Source code in VB.NET**

```
Public Class CodeCoverage2
   Public Sub DoWork(Optional ByVal flag As Boolean = False)
      Try
            Thread.Sleep(1)

            If flag Then
                Throw New Exception("test")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(String.Format("something happened: {0}", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Source code for MSTests**

```
[TestClass]
public class CodeCoverageTest
{
   [TestMethod]
   public void DoWorkTest()
   {
      var obj = new CodeCoverage();
      obj.DoWork();
   }

   [TestMethod]
   [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
   public void DoWorkTest2()
   {
      var obj = new CodeCoverage();
      obj.DoWork(true);
   }

   [TestMethod]
   public void DoWorkTest3()
   {
      var obj = new CodeCoverage2();
      obj.DoWork();
   }

   [TestMethod]
   [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
   public void DoWorkTest4()
   {
      var obj = new CodeCoverage2();
      obj.DoWork(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Post your codes here instead of screenshots

Comment: @Raptor - I used screenshots to show the code coverage (blue and yellow) in source code. Would it help if I share my source too?

Comment: Yes. You should do so.

Comment: What happens if you specify false as parameter for your DoWork instead of just relying on the optional parameter?

Comment: Just trying to run this up myself to reproduce the problem but the first thing I'd do is break it down into as many separate pieces as possible (e.g. `Dim var1 = ex.Message` as the first line) and then see which line(s) are then marked as not covered. Is it just some of them or all of them?

Comment: Can't reproduce in VS2013 (100% coverage) so it may have been an issue that was later fixed. Can't run up a 2010 instance at the moment.

Comment: @Raptor - Updated my question with source code. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - Tried your sugestion. Same behavior. No dice.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - After breaking the Catch block into two lines, one to initalize the message string and another to throw the exception, I see full code coverage for the 1st line and partial code coverage for the 2nd line. This is expected I guess. Appreciate you verifying the correct behavior in VS 2013. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the IL generated for the VB project in debug mode, you will see the following in the catch block:

```
IL_002f: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string, object)
IL_0034: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Exception::.ctor(string)
IL_0039: throw

IL_003a: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::ClearProjectError()
IL_003f: leave.s IL_0041
```

Since `IL_0039` throws, you would never hit `IL_003a`, so you have code that never gets executed.

In release mode, the IL for ClearProjectError is not generated.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Did you see what the C# IL looks like since it shows 100% code coverage? Will try out later, asked you since you may have seen it already. Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed that C# IL doesn't have lines IL_003a and IL_003f. I believe this is why code coverage differs. Will accept your answer now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough reputation to comment on John Koerner's reply, which is correct, but to add - we solved this by having our test target run in release mode.  This causes code coverage to work properly.

EG:

```
DEBUG Configuration:  
MyApplication - RELEASE ANY CPU  
MyTests - DEBUG ANY CPU
```

Results:

```
Old:  DEBUG/DEBUG - 1 line missed  N-1/N % coverage  
New:  RELEASE/DEBUG - 0 lines missed, 100 % coverage
```

Thank you John for pointing us in the right direction of looking at the IL.